# Multiple criteria MATCH/INDEX combination returns wrong row number

Tags: excel, indexing, match, criteria

I've been struggling with this for a day and can't find where is the problem.

I am recreating a table for SQL import so from table 1 I need to create a list of unique rows to have row structure. 
I can identify the unique row by two columns (ID_concept, ID_country) and then find the unique value by row of years (ID_year - top row 7,8,9,10...44).

The source table looks like this: [Source table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irljb.png)

To get the values in single rows I have created a second table to use multiple index/match combination that writes value per row. It looks like this: [Desired table for SQL import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHgQq.png)

In the value column I use following INDEX/MATCH formula to look for the data:

```
{=INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$AN$2813;MATCH(Sheet2!A2&Sheet2!B2;Sheet1!$A$2:$A$2813&Sheet1!$B$2:$B$2813;0);MATCH(Sheet2!C2;Sheet1!$C$1:$AN$1;0))}
```

When I copy the formula across Sheet2, it populates all value fields in the value column but some of the values are copied wrong. The combination of ID_concept and ID_country in the MATCH function should always lead to a unique row. I have checked the MATCHES separately and the column match works always fine. Unfortunately the row match (that uses & statement) returns in few cases wrong row number (e.g. 32 instead of 395, **input values 11 and 41 and returns row for 1 and 140**).

Range of values:
**ID_concept: 1-38**, **ID_country: 1-190**, **years: 7-44**, **Source table 2812x38**, **SQL table 106 856 rows**

Any ideas why is the multiple criteria MATCH returning wrong row information?

Thanks

Comment: Well, I ended up by hard copying the columns to the other sheet (lost 20 minutes vs. 1 day coding an elementary task). But still would appreciate for future use why 99 row numbers in +/-2800 are displayed wrong.

Comment: Make sure the "relative addresses" in your formula are changing the way you need them to as you copy/fill the formula across the sheet.

Comment: Checked and that is correct. In a non-repeating pattern it throws a completely different number. Formatting of cells is also same for all data.

Comment: You don't provide enough information in your question for me to reproduce your problem. But so long as you have found a solution ...

Comment: I will try to include a reduced version of table here.

Comment: To make the data useful edit your question to post it as **text**, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this using formulas, you can easily create your output table, in Excel, by using `Power Query` (*available in Excel 2010 or later*).

In 2016+, go to the data tab and select Get & Transform from Table/Range.
In earlier versions, there is a free, Microsoft-provided, add-in to install.

Then it is merely a matter of

- selecting the first two columns
- **unpivot** other columns
- rename the resultant `Attribute` column --> `ID_Period`

  - change the **Type** of this column to `Whole Number`
- Sort, if you want to, the results by selecting, in order, columns 3, then 2, then 1 as appropriate.

All of the above can be done from the UI, but here is the generated M-Code which you could paste into the advanced editor with minor changes:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID_concept", Int64.Type}, {"ID_country", Int64.Type}, {"7", type number}, {"8", type number}, {"9", type number}, {"10", type number}, {"11", type number}, {"12", type number}, {"13", type number}, {"14", type number}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ID_concept", "ID_country"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Attribute", "ID_Period"}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"ID_Period", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type1",{{"ID_Period", Order.Ascending}, {"ID_country", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]